# Odd behavior of Excel DisplayAlerts: "one or more invalid references" error message

Tags: python, excel, com, alerts

I have a Python script which populates Excel files with data from various sources, using Excel's COM interface. Here's a snippet:

```
file=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
#various manipulation goes here
file.DisplayAlerts=False
sheet.Delete()
file.DisplayAlerts=True
```

I need to delete one of the sheets after everything is populated, so I turn DisplayAlerts off so it doesn't ask me to confirm the deletion. I want to turn it on again afterwards, so users don't lose data. However, after DisplayAlerts is back on, switching sheets gives me this message: "A formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references. Verify that your formulas contain a valid path, workbook, range name, and cell reference". I don't normally get this message, and all of my formulas are working as expected. How can I avoid the message?

I'm pretty sure that the message has to do with the fact that I have charts which have a lot of #N/A values in their data ranges (so points don't get drawn). But what can I do to get rid of these messages, and why do they show up after those three lines of code? Also, just switching DisplayAlerts off and on again doesn't bring up the message: the deletion plays a role in this.

Also, is there some good reason for why that message doesn't just tell you where it sees a problem?

The message comes up only the first time a sheet is switched to, and returns every time an edit is made to the chart's range. Also, it doesn't come up if I just delete the sheet without turning off DisplayAlerts.

Comment: `#N/A` is not an invalid reference, did you try to find (Ctrl+F) `#REF!` in all your sheets?

Comment: @deathApril Yes, I did; there's no #REF visible. However, if I delete every single line in my chart's range, the chart shows one point (1,1) and its range suddenly contains #REF!. No idea where that's coming from.